# Bamboo Installation - Win 2012

Tags: bamboo, bamboo-artifacts

Bamboo version 6.1
Java version : 1.8.x
The JAVA_HOME was set fine.
OS : Win 2012 server

When tried running the InstallAsaService.bat - got the below response.

```
C:\Program Files\Bamboo>"C:\Program Files\Bamboo\bin\service.bat"
```

> The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
>   This environment variable is needed to run this program
>   NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE

Anyone faced similar issues and any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm answering late but this may be helpful for other users.

As per your logs, seems you have not set environment variables correctly

> JRE_HOME is corresponding path to JRE in java installation directory. 
>   JAVA_HOME is corresponding path to JDK in java installation directory.

Check your java installation and environment variable status with below command:

> java -version 
>   javac -version

Hope this will help!